# Troubleshooting Puppet Manifests for Windows puppet Node

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, librarian-puppet

I have puppet manifests which would download exe file and get installed in windows server.I am getting an error while running command: puppet agent -t on windows server.

Manifests file: /etc/puppet/modules/mercury/manifests/iisserver.pp

```
class mercury::iisserver {
        download_file { "Download dotnet core 2":
        url => 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/A/73A3E4DC-F019-47D1-9951-0453676E059B/dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-win-gs-x64.exe',
         destination_directory => 'C:/dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-win-gs-x64.ex',
        notify => Package["dotnercore2"],
    }
    package { "dotnercore2":
        ensure => installed,
        source => "C:/dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-win-gs-x64.exe",
        require => File["C:/dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-win-gs-x64.exe"],
    }
}
```

Error on windows server after running Puppet agent -t:

> Error :Could not retreive catalog from remote server:error 400 on server:Syntax error at 'Stdlib::HTTPUrl'; Expected')' at /etc/puppet/modules/download_file/manifests/init.pp on node XXXX
>
> Warning : not using cache on failed catalog.
> Error: Could not retrieve catalog; Skipping run

Comment: I'm not familiar with puppet, but are you sure that pp file start and end with backticks?

Comment: By mistake, I have put backticks. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, your error output shows what is wrong. There is a Syntax error with your HTTPUrl on your /etc/puppet/modules/download_file/manifests/init.pp file. It is expecting a ')' character somewhere. Could you recheck your manifest for the download_file module or post it here so that we can review :)